# Quick way to create an "optionalized" type from another type?

Tags: typescript

If I have this type `Thing`:

```js
type Thing = {
  prop1: string,
  prop2: number,
  // etc
}
```

is there a quick way to create `OptionalThing`?

```js
type OptionalThing = {
  prop1?: string,
  prop2?: number,
  // etc?
}
```

I'd use this, say, for utility functions to create a custom state of type `MyState` passing just some slices of state.

```js
export const createAppState = (substates: OptionalAppState, startingState = { ...defaultAppState }): AppState => {
  let { settings, data } = substates;

  if (settings) startingState.settings = { ...defaultSettingsState, ...settings };
  if (data) {
    data.series = data.series.map(series => {
      return ({
        ...initializedFrontEndData, // start with initialized
        ...series, // merge in basic series values
        data: { // merge in values for each of the data sets
          ...initializedFrontEndSeries.data, ...series.data,
        },
      });
    });

    startingState.data = { ...defaultDataState, ...data };
  }

  return startingState;
};
```

In which case I'd want to "optionalize" the app state.

Comment: Would `Partial<Thing>` do what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
const x : Partial<Thing> = { prop1 : 'val'};
```

Comment: It looks like `Partial` doesn't optionalize the entire object tree. For example, it doesn't make `prop3: SomeObject` into `prop3?: Partial<SomeObject>`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @JonathanTuzman not as far as I know, there are some `deep partial` tricks, but not as general solution, for example when you have nested tree style you can make it deep partial

Comment: @JonathanTuzman it's worth to submit a new question about  deep partial